# Rotate Cube and track its sides

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voxel

I have been attempting to solve a problem to rotate a Voxel (3d cube) and keep track of the sides once its rotated.

Take this image for example.
[image]

After rotation I need to know where the sides are after. For example if I rotated this cube on its Z axis 90 degrees, the Y and X would be swapped.

This is for a server side mod of a 3d voxel game written in Unity. So Unity methods/utils are available too. But again this is server side and a mod so I dont have access to the mesh or object itself, I can only tell it to rotate x, y or z and need to perform logic based on the final rotation. If someone can point me in a general direction or show me a method that can accomplish this I would be grateful. Thanks!

EDIT: Rotation is stored in x, y, z rotation

Comment: How do you store the rotation?

Comment: Its accepts x,y,z float but only worried about 90, 180, 270 rotations on each axis

Comment: If you want to know the right face, transform `(1, 0, 0)` with the rotation and see where it points to. Same for the other faces.

Comment: I dont have the object itself, Theres nothing to transform. I have a block Vector3Int position and the ability to give the mod API a x,y,z rotation. I need a method to rotate the block and know what side is Z+ is  on after rotation for example.

Comment: So these three ints are Euler angles? Then you can transform your vector with those.

Comment: Yes they are Euler angles, Could you show me an example?

Comment: E.g., a rotation of vector `(x, y, z)` by 90° about the x-axis is `(x, -z, y)`. Repeat that as many times as your rotation mandates. Then continue with the other two axes. Rotation about y-axis is `(z, y, -x)` and rotation about z-axis is `(-y, x, z)`.

Comment: given it will always  know where up was relative to the original you should be easily able to keep track of a given side.

Comment: Could someone provide an example of how I could do this? I am not familiar with unity itself,.I am an enterprise developer lol. I am just learning this stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/JBurlison/Pandaros.Settlers/blob/master/Pandaros.Settlers/Pandaros.Settlers/Items/ConnectedBlocks/ConnectedBlockCalculator.cs#L85

Here is a link to where I need to do the rotation. I made a best guess but does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit "stupid" solution but I would simply store the according side names in an array and perform the according value shift for each 90° step arround a certain axis.

So let's say e.g. at the default state you have

```
0 : X_l
1 : Z_u
2 : Y_l
3 : Z_l
4 : Y_u
5 : X_u
```

then actual all you need to know is the change matrix for one 90° step for each axis and each direction (`+` or `-`):

**X Axis**

```
                     positive step              negative step

original index    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5      0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
new index         0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 5      0 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0
```

**Y Axis**

```
                     positive step              negative step

original index    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5      0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
new index         3 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1      1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 3
```

**Z Axis**

```
                     positive step              negative step

original index    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5      0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
new index         4 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 2      2 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 4
```

---

I implemented this in a class `Cube` like

```c#
// The possible names of your cube sides
public enum CubeSideName
{
    X_l,
    X_u,
    Y_l,
    Y_u,
    Z_l,
    Z_u
}

// This stores the relationship between one certain
// position (Front,Back,Top,Bottom,Right,Left)
// and a cube side (x_l, x_u, y_l, y_u, z_l, z_u)
[Serializable]
public struct CubeSidePair
{
    // For the example I used GameObjects with according names
    // instead of GameObjects you could also simply have a string ID or another enum 
    // for the name of the according position
    public GameObject GameObject;
    public CubeSideName Name;
}

[Serializable]
public class Cube
{
    // This stores which position (Front,Back,Top,Bottom,Right,Left)
    // is currently taken by which cube side (x_l, x_u, y_l, y_u, z_l, z_u)
    public CubeSidePair[] CubeSidesPair = new CubeSidePair[6];

    public Vector3Int Rotation
    {
        get { return _rotation; }
        set
        {
            UpdateRotation(value);
        }
    }

    // This is actually just for making it visual
    private readonly Dictionary<CubeSideName, Color> colors = new Dictionary<CubeSideName, Color>(6)
    {
        {CubeSideName.X_u, Color.blue },
        {CubeSideName.X_l, Color.cyan },

        {CubeSideName.Y_u, Color.red },
        {CubeSideName.Y_l, Color.magenta },

        {CubeSideName.Z_u,Color.green },
        {CubeSideName.Z_l,Color.yellow }
    };

    [Header("Debug only")]
    [SerializeField] private Vector3Int _rotation;

    public void Reset()
    {
        _rotation = Vector3Int.zero;

        CubeSidesPair[0].Name = CubeSideName.X_l;
        CubeSidesPair[1].Name = CubeSideName.Z_u;
        CubeSidesPair[2].Name = CubeSideName.Y_l;
        CubeSidesPair[3].Name = CubeSideName.Z_l;
        CubeSidesPair[4].Name = CubeSideName.Y_u;
        CubeSidesPair[5].Name = CubeSideName.X_u;

        UpdateColors();
    }

    // Here all the magic happens
    private void UpdateRotation(Vector3Int newRotaion)
    {
        // get difference to current rotation
        var newRotationInput = newRotaion - _rotation;

        // Go in 90° steps around the according axis
        // untilt he rotation is done
        while (newRotationInput != Vector3Int.zero)
        {
            // For each rotation step just take the index matrices from before
            // and use them to perform an array shift
            if (newRotationInput.x < 0)
            {
                // do negative X rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[1].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[1].Name = CubeSidesPair[2].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[2].Name = CubeSidesPair[3].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[3].Name = CubeSidesPair[4].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[4].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.x += 90;
            }
            else if (newRotationInput.x > 0)
            {
                // do positive X rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[4].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[4].Name = CubeSidesPair[3].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[3].Name = CubeSidesPair[2].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[2].Name = CubeSidesPair[1].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[1].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.x -= 90;
            }
            else if (newRotationInput.y < 0)
            {
                // do negative Y rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[1].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[1].Name = CubeSidesPair[0].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[0].Name = CubeSidesPair[3].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[3].Name = CubeSidesPair[5].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[5].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.y += 90;
            }
            else if (newRotationInput.y > 0)
            {
                // do positive Y rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[3].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[3].Name = CubeSidesPair[0].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[0].Name = CubeSidesPair[1].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[1].Name = CubeSidesPair[5].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[5].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.y -= 90;
            }
            else if (newRotationInput.z < 0)
            {
                // do negative Z rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[2].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[2].Name = CubeSidesPair[0].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[0].Name = CubeSidesPair[4].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[4].Name = CubeSidesPair[5].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[5].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.z += 90;
            }
            else if (newRotationInput.z > 0)
            {
                // do positive Z rotation
                var temp = CubeSidesPair[4].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[4].Name = CubeSidesPair[0].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[0].Name = CubeSidesPair[2].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[2].Name = CubeSidesPair[5].Name;
                CubeSidesPair[5].Name = temp;

                newRotationInput.z -= 90;
            }
        }

        _rotation = newRotaion;

        UpdateColors();
    }

    // Just for the visual
    private void UpdateColors()
    {
        foreach (var cubeSide in CubeSidesPair)
        {
            var renderer = cubeSide.GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();

            renderer.material.color = colors[cubeSide.Name];
        }
    }
}
```

---

And here is how I used it for the demo (see bottom):

```c#
public class CubeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Cube Cube;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Initial setup
        Cube.Reset();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var multiplier = 90;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            multiplier = -90;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            Cube.Rotation += Vector3Int.right * multiplier;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
        {
            Cube.Rotation += Vector3Int.up * multiplier;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            Cube.Rotation += new Vector3Int(0, 0, 1) * multiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

I hope I could visualize the idea a bit ;)

I only rotated stepwise ofcourse but it shoudd work the same way if entering a fixed rotation like

```c#
Cube.Rotation = new Vector3(-90, 180, 270);
```

However, you might want to change the order in which the rotations are done.